# How to add diffrent css class to html for every foreach loop in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

**KnockoutJS Data**

```
function ExampleViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.ExampleData = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.update = function() {
        $.ajax("test.json", {
            success: function(allData) {
                var mappeddata = $.map(allData, function(item) {
                    return new DataItem(item)
                });
                self.ExampleData(mappeddata);
            }
        });
    }
}

function DataItem(data) {
    this.Name = ko.observable(data.name);
}
var exampleViewModel = new ExampleViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(exampleViewModel);
```

**Html Data**

```
    <div data-bind="foreach: ExampleData">
      <div class="has-topic-background-color">
      </div>
    </div>
```

**How I can change class of below div in every foreach loop**
  div class="has-topic-background-color

> > i need if in first loop its show red color then in second loop i need blue color insted of red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css binding

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.data = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
  self.className = function(index) {
    return index % 2 === 0? 'redClass' : 'blueClass';
  };
  self.textValue = function(index) {
    return 'Data  for index ' + index + ' has background ' + self.className(index);
  }
}   

$(document).ready(function () {
  var myViewModel = new ViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
  You can inspect the element to see the class name
</div>
<br/>

<div data-bind="foreach: data">
  <div data-bind="text: $parent.textValue($index()), css: $parent.className($index())"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hello sir nice to see you again using this css class will be change every loop with my custom css classes ?

Comment: I'm modifying to a better solution

Comment: I always try to put the logic in the javascript file

Comment: its condition if i need to add 3-4 class then what i need to do sir ?

Comment: You can put more conditions inside className function

Comment: :( i try but i fail to insert more than 2 class in knockout js

Comment: The condition for the switch is wrong. Do you know what will `index % 2` do? https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic

Comment: Item per page= 2%(module) 2==0 then execute first condition right ?   And here i got 2 items on all page

Comment: its working without pagination but in pagination with self.DataPerPage = ko.observable(2)  when swift to next page its call first two class

Comment: The problem here is you're showing the `$index` not the `$data`

Comment: sorry but can you give me fiddle example so i can understand better ? please